# Displaying file name of copying file in Progress dialog (Async Task)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

```
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Moving..");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            return  progressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

// AsyncTask for the Progress Dialog and to do Background Process
    private  class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<File, String, String> {         
        File sourceFile;         

        @Override         
        protected void onPreExecute() {             
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Shows Progress Bar Dialog and then call doInBackground method
            showDialog(0);

            }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(File... params) {

            sourceFile = params[0];
            // code to copy file
    // setting file name of copying filename                
                    **progressDialog.setMessage(children[i]);**
                    publishProgress("" + (count * 100) / children.length);

        }       
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

            progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }
        @Override         
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {             
            progressDialog.dismiss();   
            if(result==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File(s) moved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }      

    }
```

I need to display file names of copying file . I am using Async Task to copy                the file in background. I am able to get the filename of 1st file .But after that the app crashes. Any way how to set the text in ProgressDialog for this?

Logcat :

04-23 00:42:26.474: E/AndroidRuntime(26708):    at android.app.AlertDialog.setMessage(AlertDialog.java:185)
04-23 00:42:26.474: E/AndroidRuntime(26708):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.setMessage(ProgressDialog.java:314)
04-23 00:42:26.474: E/AndroidRuntime(26708):    at com.siju.instaclassify.MainActivity$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:357)
04-23 00:42:26.474: E/AndroidRuntime(26708):    at com.siju.instaclassify.MainActivity$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-23 00:42:26.474: E/AndroidRuntime(26708):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)

Answer (score 0):

Add a private variable String ProgressMessage; to your asynctask class.

```
 String ProgressMessage= "";

 protected String doInBackground(File... params) {

        sourceFile = params[0];

        ProgressMessage = sourceFile;

        publishProgress("" + (count * 100) / children.length);
  }      

  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
      progressDialog.setMessage ( ProgressMessage);
      progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Can u pls also tell me where should I display the no if files moved. Currently I am trying to display that in postexecute method.but dont know how to get the total count of files.  Can you pls help

Comment: Got the count also :)